# SL4 Dataform NewItemTemplate textbox value not getting bound

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight 4 application using MVVM which has a grid and dataform. the dataform 
has an EditItemTemplate and a NewItemTemplate. On Editing the EditItemTemplate code runs fine but upon adding a new item the NewItemTemplate code throws an error to the effect that barcode is required. Where could I be going wrong. Thanks in advance.

NewItemTemplate xaml code

```
<toolkit:DataField Label="Barcode :" 
        FontWeight="Bold" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Margin="1" 
        IsRequired="True" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
        Name="BarcodeId" 
        Text="{Binding Barcode.BarcodeId,Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Margin="2" 
        Width="300" 
        TabIndex="0" />
</toolkit:DataField>
```

EditItemTemplate code

```
<toolkit:DataField Label="Barcode :" 
        FontWeight="Bold" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Margin="1" 
        IsRequired="False" 
        IsEnabled="True" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox Width="200"   
        Text="{Binding Barcode.BarcodeId,Mode=TwoWay}" FontWeight="Normal" />
</toolkit:DataField>
```

Comment: NewItemTemplate xaml code

<toolkit:DataField Label="Barcode :" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="1" IsRequired="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="BarcodeId" Text="{Binding Barcode.BarcodeId,Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Width="300" TabIndex="0" /></toolkit:DataField>

Comment: EditItemTemplate code

<toolkit:DataField Label="Barcode :" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="1" IsRequired="False" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
 <TextBox Width="200"   Text="{Binding Barcode.BarcodeId,Mode=TwoWay}" FontWeight="Normal" /> </toolkit:DataField>

Comment: Sorry had included the xaml in the question but was not showing

Comment: I have no idea why this is not binding

Comment: If anyone could provide me with a dataform that has the NewItemTemplate textbox which is working and some associated viewModel I would appreciate it